# How can I decode a node value of an XPath in an XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am populating a value in an XML document using an XPath and would like to have some kind of conditions for the value being displayed. This is for version 1.0 of XSLT. The XPath in the XSLT looks like the following:

```
<Id>
   <xsl:value-of select="export_service/forms/form_id" />
</Id>
```

This works fine but there are times the 'form_id' is empty and I'd like to display 'N/A' in such cases. How do I achieve that?

By the way, I have tried something like the below and this and it seems to work but not populating 'N/A' as I would expect:

```
<xsl: for-each select="//export_service/forms"
   <Id>
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="form_id != ''">
             <xsl:value-of select="form_id" />
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
             <xsl:text>N/A</xsl:text>
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </Id>
</xsl: for-each>
```

Comment: I don't know which XSLT and XPath versions you are using but you could do something like this : select="if(export_service/forms/form_id='') then 'N/A' else export_service/forms/form_id"

Comment: It's for version 1.0, tried your solution, and does not seem to work. Could you take a look at what I have and see if could achieve what I'm looking for with a slight tweak maybe?

Comment: You are on the right track with `xsl:choose`. Please post a [mcve] showing a sample input and the expected output. Otherwise it's not possible to tell why your attempt fails.

Comment: Figured out what the issue was, where I do the check <xsl:when test="form_id != ''">, I needed to have space between the quotes that represent the empty string. The moment I changed that check to <xsl:when test="form_id != ' '">, it worked as expected.

Answer (score -2):

Adding a space between two quotes that represent the empty string in check below fixed the issue:
<xsl:when test="form_id != **''**">

Comment: A space between quotes does NOT represent an empty string. It represents a string that consists of the space character. If you want to test for an element that is either empty or contains only whitespace characters, use the `normalize-space()` function. Or use the `xsl:strip-space` instruction to remove text nodes that contain only whitespace characters.